# Bootstrap links not clickable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

please see example: http://bit.ly/1H27G9I

I am trying to change the style of the standard bootstrap nav bar so that there are links on the left and right then the logo in the middle.  I have succeeded with the positioning, however then left side links are not clickable anymore. I read that it might be to do with the z-index but that didn't seem to solve the problem.

I have attached my html code with some custom css.  Any advice is greatly appreciated!

```css
.headerlogo{

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
 height: 125px;

}

.navbar-brand
{
 padding-top: 35px;
 width: 160px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -80px; /* Half the width */

}

.navbar-left {

padding-top: 35px;
padding-left: 200px;

}

.navbar-right {

padding-top: 35px;
padding-right: 200px;

}

@media (min-width: 970px){
 .navbar-default {
  height: 125px;
  background-color: #151515;
 }

 .res-img {
  max-width:160px; 
  margin-top: -15px;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 970px){
 .navbar-default {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #151515;
 }

 .res-img {
  max-width:100px; 
  margin-top: -15px;
 }
 
 .headerlogo
 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 125px;

 }

.navbar-brand
 {
   float: left;
   height: 50px;
   padding: 15px 15px;
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 20px;
 }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
 <!-- Custom CSS -->
 <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
 </head>
  <body>
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" style="border-radius:0px;">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
     
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">TILES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BATHROOMS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">INSPIRATION</a></li>
      </ul>
   
   <div class="headerlogo">
    <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="logo">
  <img class="res-img" src="img/logo.png">
  </a>
 </div>
 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">SHOWROOMS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CART</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
 </nav>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  
  </html>
```

Comment: What did you try with the z-index?

Comment: try changing the height of .headerlogo for @media (max-width: 970px) as it is overlapping your link hope it helps.

Comment: It's your custom CSS. If you turn it off everything works fine. Use bootstrap's built in classes and alignments to get the image where you want it.

Comment: The Bit.ly link doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the `height: 125px;` property on the `.headerLogo` class. This is causing the div, when at 100% width, to overlap the first menu items.

Answer (score 1):

You say you don't think it is the z-index. But by looking at your sample. I think it is. Your header logo is positioned absolute and overlapping  the links.

Doing something like this should fix it.

```
.headerlogo {
  z-index:1;
}
.navbar-left {
  position:relative;
  z-index:9;
}
```

Basically if you are going to lay it out this way, then your nav needs to have a higher z-index than your logo.

*Also note that this appears to be different depending on your screen resolution. So its quite possible you are seeing it working at some resolutions, and broken in others.*

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also apply:
z-index:10 
in css to the containing div.

Answer (score 0):

this solves the problem

```
.navbar-header {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 9001;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    z-index: 9000;
}
```