# Vanilla Bootstrap Navbar links not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a vanilla version of Bootstrap and trying to create a general template for a friend to use on all their sites.  I've used Bootstrap before with no issues, but now am having an issue.  To clarify: to my knowledge I have not altered the Bootstrap js or css code at all.

The problem is that links in the navbar are not clickable.

HTML Beginning

```
<head>
  <title>Comic Title - Update Schedule</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <? require "walrus.php"; ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.navbar-nav a[href]').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
  });
  </script>
  <style>
  .affix {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .affix + .container-fluid {
    padding-top: 70px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#00FF00;color:#fff;height:150px;">
  <h1>Example Header</h1>
  <h3>You'll probably want a cool image here.</h3>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="150" style="z-index: 1001;">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a class="link" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="http://www.google.com">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="http://www.google.com">Characters</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="page.php?p=archive">Archive</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Posts I have looked at and have not worked (or were not permanent solution):
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554349/bootstrap-3-navbar-links-not-working) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109427/bootstrap-links-not-clickable).

Comment: **$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.navbar-nav a[href]').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
  });**, please remove this and it will work.

Comment: plus one for the cat image

Comment: I've trimmed a fair bit of commentary (about what sort of code readers would like to see) and the link to your site, since both are now redundant given that the question is resolved (as soon as you fix the problem on the remote site, it will no longer demonstrate the problem at hand). The best questions here are the ones that are written for posterity rather than for a temporary requirement - thus if you can evidence the problem in a way that will be understandable in six months time, that will allow future readers to learn from it too. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script you have in your HTML is what is preventing the links from being clickable.

Anchor tags are by default, clickable, however your jQuery function is using the event method, preventDefault, which does exactly what it says, prevents the anchor tags default event; being clickable.

Good luck!

Comment: Somehow I'd completely skipped over this script section about 10 times, probably because I'm still learning javascript.  Thanks!